# Add multiple hyperlinks in facebook status message

Tags: facebook

Was just wondering if there is there a way through which you can add multiple hyperlinks with text on a facebook status message. Though there is friend tagging, is there a way through which I would be able to add multiple URL's in a single status message.

for e.g:

```
Hey guys check this out! [Google Hotpot][1]! [SomeRandomWebsite][2]! and [SomeOtherWebsite][3]!
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Graph API and post multiple hyperlinks in the message. I just tested on mine and it worked perfectly.  Check it out here:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer